# Expression that returns all currently scoped symbols in Clojure?

Tags: debugging, clojure, symbols

Assume the following,

```
(in-ns silly.fun)

(def a 1)

(defn fx [b]
  ((fn [c] (return-all-symbols)) (first b)))
```

I was wondering if it is possible to have a return-all-symbols function that would return the map of symbols/values currently scoped at its invocation. So, assuming the above was compiled and we were in the 'silly.fun namespace, we could run something like the following.

```
(fx [:hello]) => {"a" 1, "b" [:hello], "c" :hello}
```

I would like to use return-all-symbols for debugging purposes. Is return-all-symbols at all possible? If so, what is its implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but as you've defined it you'd be pretty sad: you don't want a map with hundreds of entries referring to all the functions in clojure.core! And even if you only look in the current namespace, you forgot to include `fx`, which is a symbol whose value is a function. Plus there will often be lexical symbols you don't want, introduced by macros. eg, `(let [[x y] foo])` would show four symbols available: foo, x, y, and something like `vec__auto__4863`.

Anyway, you probably have to live with some compromise over those issues, or else (and really I think this is better) specify which symbols you actually want a map of. But to automatically get values for those symbols which are either (a) lexical or (b) defined in the current namespace, and also (c) not mapping to a function, you could use:

```
(defmacro return-all-symbols []
  (let [globals (remove (comp :macro meta val) (ns-publics *ns*))
        syms (mapcat keys [globals, &env])
        entries (for [sym syms]
                  [`(quote ~sym) sym])]
    `(into {}
           (for [[sym# value#] [~@entries]
                 :when (not (fn? value#))]
             [sym# value#]))))


(def a 1)

(defn fx [b]
  ((fn [c] (return-all-symbols)) (first b)))

(fx [:hello])
;=> {a 1, c :hello, b [:hello]}
```

Comment: It's going to take some time to really parse through what you did, but I tried it and it seems to work. Color me impressed.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces contain a map with all the currently scoped vars, which gives you part of what you want. It would miss lexicaly scoped symbols from expressions like `(let [x 4] (return-all-symbols))` though may still be useful for debugging:

```
core> (take 2 (ns-map *ns*))
([sorted-map #'clojure.core/sorted-map] [read-line #'clojure.core/read-line])
```

if you need more than this then you may need a real debugger that uses the java debugging
interface. check out [the clojure debugging toolkit](http://georgejahad.com/clojure/cdt.html)

Answer (score 2):

[(ns-interns)](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-interns) might be what you want, but using [(ns-map)](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-map) wrapped in [(lazy-seq)](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq) works good for a big namespace.

```
1   (ns-map 'clojure.core)
2   {sorted-map #'clojure.core/sorted-map, read-line #'clojure.core/read-line, re-pattern #'clojure.core/re-pattern, keyword? #'clojure.core/keyword?, ClassVisitor clojure.asm.ClassVisitor, asm-type #'clojure.core/asm-type, val #'clojure.core/val, ...chop...}
```